# Excel to XML invalid token

Tags: xml, vb.net, excel, dictionary

Hi I am currently creating an Excel file that will go into a VB project. I'm going to convert the Excel file into a XML file using one of the Excel developer tools. I have made a map but, this isn't working and I am getting an error. The error I get is on line 5, column 2.

When i found out I had the error I ran it in XML Copy Editor: `"Error on line 5, column 2 isn't well formed, invalid token."`

Any idea how I can fix this?

Cheers,
Steve

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<data-set xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<record>
<C>0</C>
<0>0.0</0>
<1>0</1>
<2>0</2>
<3>-0.001</3>
<4>0.001</4>
<5>-0.001</5>
<6>-0.001</6>
<7>-0.001</7>
<8>-0.001</8>
<9>-0.002</9>
<10>-0.002</10>

</record>
<record>
<C>10</C>
<0>-0.002</0>
<1>-0.002</1>
<2>-0.002</2>
<3>-0.002</3>
<4>-0.002</4>
<5>-0.002</5>
<6>-0.002</6>
<7>-0.002</7>
<8>-0.003</8>
<9>-0.003</9>
<10>-0.003</10>

</record>

</data-set>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Among other restrictions, XML element names [cannot start with a number](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_elements.asp).  You may want to prefix your numeric values with a letter; if they're row values, `<R01>` etc.